# Using Storybook with Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, storybook

I have a simple component that uses Redux and Redux Sagas. The action is dispatched when a button is clicked and it changes the state value asynchronously.

I am creating a storybook component for this and I have already set up a decorator that uses the Provider(the store has been configured).

The storybook component gets the desired state value, however, it fails to dispatch the action.

I am unable to figure out what is the reason behind this. I am new to Storybook, any idea why the action is not dispatching?